# How to install 32-bit docker container

Tags: docker

I'm trying to create a 32-bit docker image with Ubuntu 14.04 and, any time that I run `uname`, I see that it is `x86_64` instead of `i386`. Could anyone tell me why this is happening?

```bash
docker run talex5/lucid32 uname -m
```

The weird thing is when I look up the architecture type a different way, it says 32-bit:

```bash
docker run i386/ubuntu:14.04 file /sbin/init
```

> /sbin/init: ELF 32-bit LSB  shared object, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=c394677bccc720a3bb4f4c42a48e008ff33e39b1, stripped`

This happens consistently whenever I download different docker images that say they are 32-bit and even when I create my own docker image using debootstrap.

Thanks!

Comment: To change the output of `uname` use the `setarch` command.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`uname` reports the version and OS details of the kernel, but Docker containers always use the host system's kernel, and if it's a 64-bit kernel it will report `x86_64`.

You should see the same results running this with a mixed 32-/64-bit OS install (in Ubuntu land installing packages like `libc6:i686`); with a 32-bit filesystem tree in a chroot; and in a Docker container; which are all the same case of running 32-bit binaries on a system with a 64-bit kernel.

Answer (score -1):

This is possible these days, with just a simple script. You could use https://github.com/docker-32bit/ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Running that script and executing `uname -i` also gives `x86_64`

Comment: Have you tried like [this](https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/how-to-install-docker-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts/) too?